# storm unknown error: can't emit message to another bolt

Tags: apache-storm, emit

I am using strom to analysis some log, but when one bolt emit one log  to another bolt, the code will stop and storm is sitll running, the log content is as following:

```
{'request-content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'src': '127.0.0.1:60978', 'response-body': '{"status":200,"message":"OK","data":{"winNoticeAttach":"\xe7\x82\xb9\xe5\x87\xbb\xe6\x9f\xa5\xe7\x9c\x8b\xe6\xb4\xbb\xe5\x8a\xa8\xe8\xaf\xa6\xe6\x83\x85\xe3\x80\x82","value":"http:\\/\\/h5.ffan.com\\/zzq\\/h5\\/s.html?imgcode=T1ypLTB5YT1RCvBVdK&title=%E5%81%9C%E8%BD%A6%E8%A7%82%E5%BD%B1%EF%BC%8C%E6%9C%80%E9%AB%98%E5%85%A8%E5%85%8D%EF%BC%8C%E5%97%A8%E5%97%A8%E5%97%A8%EF%BC%81","type":"99","detailId":"7644","lable":"\xe5\x81\x9c\xe8\xbd\xa6\xe8\xa7\x82\xe5\xbd\xb1\xef\xbc\x8c\xe6\x9c\x80\xe9\xab\x98\xe5\x85\xa8\xe5\x85\x8d\xef\xbc\x8c\xe5\x97\xa8\xe5\x97\xa8\xe5\x97\xa8\xef\xbc\x81"}}', 'request-url': '/shake/v2/lottery/luck?puid=BF31A0E5914044D8B7885BDF8D278677&FFUDID=15000000076773092&ddId=ef81733907ae23b4c63vvbxhp48406ac&uid=15000000076773092&wdId=3c57787ee317fa3d6f842116213e85ad&pLoginToken=d2efe8e5e4540ad611aa84a46b330148&__uni_source=1.1', 'dst': '10.209.240.68:10982', 'request-body': 'FFClientType=1&FFClientVersion=42100000&FFUDID=15000000076773092&__uni_source=1.1&app_code=02ac65ddc46dc38fe482781d2a44a3a0901cb5fbf814c607b7&app_time=14682269272312&cityId=150400&ddId=ef81733907ae23b4c63vvbxhp48406ac&devInfo=%257B%2522locationProvince%2522%253A%2522%2522%252C%2522locationY%2522%253A%2522%2522%252C%2522IP%2522%253A%2522192.168.1.1%2522%252C%2522locationCity%2522%253A%2522%2522%252C%2522network_desc%2522%253A%2522WIFI%2522%252C%2522locationDistrict%2522%253A%2522%2522%252C%2522device_id%2522%253A%2522ef81733907ae23b4c63vvbxhp48406ac%2522%252C%2522sourceFrom%2522%253A%2522APP%2522%252C%2522wifi%2522%253A%2522CMCC%2522%252C%2522size%2522%253A%2522320%252A568%2522%252C%2522Os_type%2522%253A%2522IOS%2522%252C%2522device_desc%2522%253A%2522iPhone8%252C2%2522%252C%2522mac%2522%253A%2522ef81733907ae23b4c63vvbxhp48406ac%2522%252C%2522locationX%2522%253A%2522%2522%252C%2522locationAddress%2522%253A%2522%2522%252C%2522network%2522%253A%2522WIFI%2522%252C%2522GPS%2522%253A%2522%2522%252C%2522os_version%2522%253A%2522iPhone%2520OS%25209.3%2522%252C%2522screenSize%2522%253A%2522320%252A568%2522%252C%2522gmtTime%2522%253A%2522Sat%252C%25204%2520Jun%25202016%252014%253A27%253A05%2520GMT%2522%257D&pLoginToken=d2efe8e5e4540ad611aa84a46b330148&puid=BF31A0E5914044D8B7885BDF8D278677&uid=15000000076773092&version=1&wdId=3c57787ee317fa3d6f842116213e85ad', 'request-hc': 88, 'request-host': 'api.ffan.com', 'response-content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'request-method': 'POST', 'request-cookie': 'SESSIONID=1f6ba1041587a7135cfa1a6d42e2d5ef; psid=58ff1f469875dab75f9a080eb81e5033; puid=BF31A0E5914044D8B7885BDF8D278677; up=bup; sid=d2efe8e5e4540ad611aa84a46b330148; uid=15000000076773092; uniqkey2=RZhczLgfkoQJoTrJFEDKGZ/zXILl/QZZjYcK8eb8DAWp0Y9bkRmQEjIw/JbBUyzzmK7d4I8KAlNbEgeS83MSxmnhWAdTxpyBCBwOflYxLXb1XDZ3cd1h2iPX2lJcUjdiR81xlD1iGqOZS9xI6wHsYTj0ctfnWmX/pXPl9Ls9zIv4HWeFf4thJ9qirL2TgKMcgNLw', 'response-code': 200, 'request-x-forwarded-for': '1217.0.0.1', 'time': '2016-07-11 16:48:49', 'request-referer': 'https://api.ffan.com/shake/v2/lottery/luck?puid=BF31A0E5914044D8B7885BDF8D278677&FFUDID=15000000076773092&ddId=ef81733907ae23b4c63vvbxhp48406ac&uid=15000000076773092&wdId=3c57787ee317fa3d6f842116213e85ad&pLoginToken=d2efe8e5e4540ad611aa84a46b330148&__uni_source=1.1 ', 'response-content-length': '377', 'request-user-agent': 'com.dianshang.wanhui/4.2.1 (iPhone; iOS 9.3; Scale/2.00)', 'id': 'b18d2e7f-5017-4fc7-af32-f16c8d6fdcc3'}
```

it seems the bolt can't emit this message to another, I am stucked and did't know how to find why this is error..

to describe my question clearly, I will give how my code runs:

(1)there is a c program to capture the network packet on the specified interface, eg eth0, and then put the packet into one json data, as I mentioned above, then put it in one redis queue.

(2)I write a spout with pyleus, the spout will fetch data from the redis queue and use **json.loads()** to translate the data to python dict and emit the data to boltA.

(3)boltA receive the dict and try to decode something, for the response in the dict is base64 encode, after decode the response body it will emit the dict to boltB.

now my problem is when boltA decode the response body it can't emit the body to boltB,but if boltA doesn't decode response body, it will work well.
I think if there is some specified charater which storm can't work with...

I try everything I know and can't solve this..

hope I describe my question clearly..

Comment: Your question is not very precise... Thus, nobody will be able to help you... Did you have a look into the logs for errors?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, I didn't  know how to describe my quesiton clearly. I check all the storm log and my code log, there is no error,i

Comment: No idea. If you do not find a better way to ask, you will not get any help. Your question reads like "Why is my code not working"...

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I edit my problem, hope I describe it clearly..sorrry for my bad english

Comment: Don't worry about your English. :) The problem right now is, that there is no error in the logs. What do you exactly mean by "code will stop"? Is Bolt.execute not called anymore? You could also increase the log-level to get more details -- if this is really a bug in Storm, you should write to dev mailing list to get some help there -- SO is not the right place to track down Storm bugs (if it might be one). No other idea so far.

Comment: "code will stop" mean the boltA will not emit tuple to BoltB while the Spout  still running.

Comment: Maybe you can post some sample code.  Do you mean it boltA will emit whether it decodes or not and boltB receives it when it doesn't decode, but doesn't otherwise?